# How to resolve Xcode pull conflict with json file

Tags: xcode, merge, bitbucket, conflict, pull

Im trying to pull master data changes to my current branch in Xcode. But there is a json file difference which I am not able to resolve and Xcode has no options to select left or right during json file comparison.

How to resolve the conflict and pull the data in Xcode or how to use bitbucket command line to resolve pull conflict.

Comment: please give us screenshot of git conflict

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved it by adding updated json file manually in code then pushed the code. Thats it